# SYNC folder with server in drive D

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-7, synchronization, login-script

i am using windows 2003 server and windows 7 as client.

i have one folder in drive D i want to SYNC that folder with server.

how can i write login script for that?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The robocopy command is bundled with Windows 7 and allows you sync a folder to another destination.  Try adding robocopy to your login script like this:

```
robocopy d:\path\to\source s:\path\to\destination /MIR /Z
```

The /MIR option ensures that the destination folder always reflects the source folder.